# Reset locked iPhone 5 without updating

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, restore

My friend gave me her old iPhone 5 (iOS 10.3.2) which she can't remember the passcode to and I need to factory reset it from iTunes. I have tried doing this by putting the phone into recovery mode and trying to restore it but iTunes wants to update the phone to iOS 10.3.3. Because I have a poor internet each time I try to restore and update, downloading iOS 10.3.3 fails.

Is there a way to restore it without using my internet?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

Afraid not, but I feel your struggle. My internet is about as terrible as it gets (14kb/s). However, I was able to download the IPSW using my PS3's Internet browser which seems to get 700kb/s and it took slightly over one hour. You might not have a PS3 but this is what worked for me.

Or likewise, you could try downloading the IPSW on a public library computer from a 3rd party website or even a friend's computer. Whatever the case, good luck.